# prevent bash completion from altering underscore variable $_

Tags: bash, autocomplete, variable

When using tab completion in bash, the `$_` variable is altered:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd <TAB><TAB> $_
bash: cd: -d: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]]] [dir]
```

(The `<TAB><TAB>` will list all files in current directory, but I don't end up using the output and write `$_` instead.  The command executed in this line will just be `cd $_`.)

Expected behavior would be to change into `./test`.

How can I prevent bash completion from altering `$_`?

Comment: bash is pretty limited with its autocompletion options: I am not sure if that is possible. If you need more powerfull and customisable autocompletion in interactive session I suggest moving to zsh if that is possible.

Comment: This is almost certainly due to programmable completion, the default (`readline`) completion doesn't do this. Please indicate which version of bash, which completion package and/or the output of `complete -p`.

Comment: `cd <TAB><TAB>` should give you all possible completions (the 2nd tab),how are you entering `$_`?

Comment: @mr.spuratic Bash version is GNU bash is version 4.2.45(2)-release on x86_64. 
The output of `complete -p` is here:
https://js.f0i.de/complete-p.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [`bash-completion`](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) package (or a derivative). For each argument completion of the `cd` command (as shown by the `complete -p` output):

```
complete -o nospace -F _cd cd
```

the `_cd` function is invoked to determine the completions (slightly edited for brevity):

```
_cd()
{
    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return

    local IFS=$'\n' i j k

    compopt -o filenames

    if [[ -z "${CDPATH:-}" || "$cur" == ?(.)?(.)/* ]]; then
        _filedir -d
        return 0
    fi
    ....
```

So for example, when you complete on a directory with no `CDPATH` set, the last-seen argument to a command seen is `-d`, and this is placed automatically in `_`. There are several other code paths in that function with similar side-effects.

Since `_` is a bash internal, a conventional save/restore (as for [`IFS`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92187/setting-ifs-for-a-single-statement)) won't work as hoped.
You *could* do it with a little trickery:

```
_cd()
{
    local save_="$_"
    ...
    : $save_
    return 0
```

You must save `_` immediately on entry to a function, `:` is the null command, which does nothing per-se but has the usual side-effects of a command, such as setting `_`. This restore operation will be required for each return point of each potentially disruptive function. There's a subtlety here too: normally `_` is set immediately after a return from a function (to the last argument of the function call, as expected), which would make this method ineffective. But, this doesn't happen when a completion function is invoked, since it's not explicit invoked. I don't consider this to be very robust...

(I prefer *history expansion*, and stick to `!$` which doesn't suffer this problem.)