# When can I use a temporary IFS for field splitting?

Tags: bash

In bash, say you have `var=a.b.c.`, then:

```
$ IFS=. printf "%s\n" $var
a.b.c
```

However, such a usage of `IFS` does take effect while creating an array:

```
$ IFS=. arr=($var)
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
a
b
c
```

This is very convenient, sure, but where is this documented? A quick reading of the sections on [Arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays) or [Word Splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting) in the Bash documentation does not give any indication either way. A search for `IFS` through [the single-page documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) doesn't provide any hints about this effect either.

I'm not sure when I can reliably do:

```
IFS=x do something
```

And expect that `IFS` will affect field splitting.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The basic idea is that `VAR=VALUE some-command` sets `VAR` to `VALUE` for the execution of `some-command` when `some-command` is an external command, and it doesn't get more fancy than that. If you combine this intuition with some knowledge of how a shell works, you should come up with the right answer in most cases. The POSIX reference is [“Simple Commands” in the chapter “Shell Command Language”](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01).

If `some-command` is an **external command**, `VAR=VALUE some-command` is equivalent to `env VAR=VALUE some-command`. `VAR` is exported in the environment of `some-command`, and its value (or lack of a value) in the shell doesn't change.

If `some-command` is a **function**, then `VAR=VALUE some-command` is equivalent to `VAR=VALUE; some-command`, i.e. **the assignment remains in place** after the function has returned, and the variable is not exported into the environment. The reason for that has to do with the design of the Bourne shell (and subsequently with backward compatibility): it had no facility to save and restore variable values around the execution of a function. Not exporting the variable makes sense since a function executes in the shell itself. However, ksh (including both ATT ksh93 and pdksh/mksh), bash and zsh implement the more useful behavior where `VAR` is set only during the execution of the function (it's also exported). In **ksh**, this is done if the function is defined with the ksh syntax `function NAME …`, not if it's defined with the standard syntax `NAME ()`. In **bash**, this is done only in bash mode, not in POSIX mode (when run with `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1`). In **zsh**, this is done if the `posix_builtins` option is not set; this option is not set by default but is turned on by `emulate sh` or `emulate ksh`.

If `some-command` is a builtin, the behavior depends on the type of builtin. **[Special builtins](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14)** behave like functions. Special built-ins are the ones that have to be implemented inside the shell because they affect the state shell (e.g. `break` affects control flow, `cd` affects the current directory, `set` affects positional parameters and options…). **Other builtins** are built-in only for performance and convenience (mostly — e.g. the bash feature `printf -v` can only be implemented by a builtin), and they behave like an external command.

The assignment takes place after alias expansion, so if `some-command` is an **alias**, expand it first to find what happens.

Note that in all cases, the assignment is performed after the command line is parsed, including any variable substitution on the command line itself. So `var=a; var=b echo $var` prints `a`, because `$var` is evaluated before the assignment takes place. And thus `IFS=. printf "%s\n" $var` uses the old `IFS` value to split `$var`.

I've covered all the types of commands, but there's one more case: when **there is no command to execute**, i.e. if the command consists only of assignments (and possibly redirections). In that case, **the assignment remains in place**. `VAR=VALUE OTHERVAR=OTHERVALUE` is equivalent to `VAR=VALUE; OTHERVAR=OTHERVALUE`. So after `IFS=. arr=($var)`, `IFS` remains set to `.`. Since you could use `$IFS` in the assignment to `arr` with the expectation that it already has its new value, it makes sense that the new value of `IFS` is used for the expansion of `$var`.

In summary, you can use `IFS` for *temporary* field splitting only:

- by starting a new shell or a subshell (e.g. `third=$(IFS=.; set -f; set -- $var; echo "$3")` is a complicated way of doing `third=${var#*.*.}` except that they behave differently when the value of `var` contains less than two `.` characters);
- in ksh, with `IFS=. some-function` where `some-function` is defined with the ksh syntax `function some-function …`;
- in bash and zsh, with `IFS=. some-function` as long as they are operating in native mode as opposed to compatibility mode.

Comment: "`IFS` remains set to `.`" Eek. After reading the first part, that makes sense, but before I posted this Q, I would not have expected that.

Comment: This is an answer to a different question

Comment: Some additional explanation in [this answer from some years ago](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92190/28412).

Answer (score 7):

The answer of @Gilles is really great, he explains (in detail) a complex issue.

However, I believe that the answer to why this command:

```
$ IFS=. printf "%s\n" $var
a.b.c
```

works as it does is the simple idea that the whole command line is **parsed before** it is executed. And that each "word" is processed once by the shell.
The [assignments, like `IFS=.`, are delayed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) (step 4 is the last one):

> 4.- Each variable assignment shall be expanded ...

until just before the command is executed and all expansions in arguments are processed first to build this executable line:

```
$ IFS=. printf "%s\n" a.b.c           ## IFS=. goes to the environment.
a.b.c
```

The value of `$var` is expanded with the "old" IFS to `a.b.c` before the command `printf` is given the arguments `"%s\n"` and `a.b.c`.

#### Eval

One level of delay may be introduced by `eval`:

```
$ IFS=. eval printf "'%s\n'" \$var
a
b
c
```

The line is parsed (1st time) and 'IFS=.' is set to the environment as this:

```
$ printf '%s\n' $var
```

Then it is parsed again to this:

```
$ printf '%s\n' a b c
```

And executed to this:

```
a
b
c
```

The value of `$var` (a.b.c) is split with the value of IFS in use: `.`.

#### Environment

The complex and tricky part is what is valid in the environment when !!!

That is explained very well in the first part of Gilles answer.

With an additional detail.

When this command is executed:

```
$ IFS=. arr=($var)
```

The value of IFS is retained in the present environment, yes:

```
$ printf '<%s>  ' "${arr[@]}" "$IFS"
<a>  <b>  <c>  <.>
```

#### IFS for a single statement.

But it could be avoided: [Setting IFS for a single statement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92190/79743)

```
$ IFS=. command eval arr\=\(\$var\)

$  printf '<%s>  ' "${arr[@]}" "$IFS"
<a>  <b>  <c>  < 
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question regarding

```
var=a.b.c
IFS=. printf "%s\n" $var
```

is a corner case.

This is because the `macro expansion` in the command happens **before** the shell variable `IFS=.`is set.

In other words: when `$var` is expanded, the previous `IFS` value active, then `IFS` is set to `'.'`.