# How do I use a temporary environment variable in a bash for loop?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, command-line, for

I want to run `YII_ENV=prod yii kw/test` ten times. I tried

```
$ YII_ENV=prod for x in 1..10 do; yii kw/test done;
-bash: for: command not found
1304682651
```

(Seemed to run once.) I also tried

```
$ for x in {1..10} do; YII_ENV=prod yii kw/test done;
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `YII_ENV=prod'
```

GNU bash, version 4.3.39(2)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)

Comment: Insert a `;` before `done`.

Comment: I think you just have misplaced semicolons? Try `for x in {1..10}; do YII_ENV=prod yii kw/test; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First correct the syntax of your command, place the semicolons correctly.   Instead of:

```
for x in 1..10 do; yii kw/test done;
```

Use (adding a correct brace expansion also):

```
for x in {1..10}; do yii kw/test; done
```

Then, add the variable:

```
for x in {1..10}; do YII_ENV=prod yii kw/test; done
```

Answer (score 11):

The syntax `VARIABLE=VALUE COMMAND` to set an environment variable for the duration of a command only works when the command is a simple command (more precisely, an external command or a builtin that acts like one — see [When can I use a temporary IFS for field splitting?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264635/when-can-i-use-a-temporary-ifs-for-field-splitting/264642#264642) for more details). You can't use it with a complex command such as a for loop.

Your first attempt failed because `for` wasn't the first word of a command, so it wasn't parsed as a keyword, so bash looked for a command called `for` instead of parsing a for loop. Your second attempt failed because of a simple syntax error in the loop: you need a semicolon or line break before `do`, again because otherwise `do` isn't recognized as a keyword. Similarly you also need a semicolon before `done`.

```
for x in {1..10}; do YII_ENV=prod yii kw/test; done
```

To set a variable for the duration of the loop, if you don't care about overwriting a previous value, just set the variable and unset it afterwards.

```
export YII_ENV=prod
for x in {1..10}; do yii kw/test; done
unset YII_ENV
```

Alternatively, run the loop in a subshell. This is an option only if the loop isn't supposed to modify the shell's environment.

```
(
  export YII_ENV=prod
  for x in {1..10}; do yii kw/test; done
)
```

Alternatively, run the loop in a function, and make the variable local to the function. This requires bash or ksh or zsh, it doesn't work in plain sh, but the `{...}` syntax has those requirements anyway.

```
call_yii () {
  typeset YII_ENV=prod
  export YII_ENV
  for x in {1..10}; do yii kw/test; done
}
```