# Is using env and export the same thing?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I'm wondering whether this (From https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps):

```
env VAR1="blahblah" command_to_run command_options
```

Is the same thing as:

```
VAR1="blahblah"
export VAR1
command_to_run ...
```

Comment: Read http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264642/38906

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not the same.

```
env VAR1="blahblah" command_to_run command_options
```

runs `command_to_run` with `VAR1="blahblah"` in its environment; the containing shell's environment isn't affected.

```
VAR1="blahblah"
export VAR1
command_to_run
```

adds `VAR1="blahblah"` to the shell's environment and makes it available for all subsequent commands, including `command_to_run`.