# Possible bug in Bash?: foo() { echo "${var[0]}"; }; var=(bar baz) foo

Tags: bash, array

**OS**: Ubuntu 16.04.3

**Shell**: Bash 4.3.48

---

I know that is possible to temporarily change the content of a variable as in `var=value command`, being probably `IFS= read -r var` the most notable case of this.

And, [thanks to Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/104), I also understand:

```
# Why this
foo() { echo "$var"; }
var=value foo

# And this does work
var=value; echo "$var"

# But this doesn't
var=value echo "$var"
```

What escapes my understanding is this:

```
$ foo() { echo "${var[0]}"; }
$ var=(bar baz) foo
(bar baz)
```

As far as I know (and following the logic of previous examples), it should print `bar`, not `(bar baz)`.

Does this only happen to me? Is this the intended behavior and I'm missing something? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that bash doesn't support arrays as environmental variables?

Comment: @Jesse_b Maybe. Though when I run `export var=(foo bar); echo "${var[0]}"` it prints `foo`, not `(foo bar)`.

Comment: Odd, that worked for me as well.  And using `export` it shows: `declare -ax var=([0]="foo" [1]="bar")`

Comment: Environment can't contain arrays, AFAIK. E.g., `export i_am_array=(foo bar); /usr/bin/env | grep i_am_array` gives no output here.

Comment: Also: `foo() { declare -p var; } ; var=(bar baz) foo` gives `declare -x var="(bar baz)"` confirming its being treated as a string, not an array

Comment: @derobert I see. But still `export var=(foo bar); declare -p var` also prints `declare -ax var='([0]="foo" [1]="bar")'`. So using `declare` to check the attributes of `var` displays both as an array and as a string. It could be that mantainers decided to add support to arrays as env variables but it's still an ongoing work?

Comment: @nxnev It definitely sounds like there is a bug somewhere... There are a bunch of inconsistent behaviors. Environment variables aren't a bash creation, so arrays in env vars aren't really possible.

Comment: Also try `var[0]=blahblah foo`

Comment: @ilkkachu It prints nothing. And if I add `declare -p var` to `foo()`, it seems that variable is unset: `bash: declare: var: not found`. So using different approaches `var` could be a string, an array or unset.

Comment: @nxnev, exactly. And `var=(aa bb); var[0]=what foo` prints `aa`, so the assignment to a member of an array doesn't happen at all.

Comment: @derobert, shells like rc, es, fish support exporting arrays using some form of encoding.

Comment: I found the useful [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264642/109397) about the `VAR=VALUE some-command` construction. Also added link to it in my answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generally calling:

```
var=value cmd
```

where `cmd` is a function is not portable.

With `bash`, that only works for scalar variables (and with `x=(...)` parsed as an array but assigned as a scalar) and there are a number of issues with scoping if you do that, with `ksh93` and `yash`, it works but the variable definition remains afterwards. With `mksh`, you get a syntax error. In the Bourne shell, it didn't work at all, even for scalar variables.

Also note that even with scalar variables, whether the variable ends up being *exported* within the function (that is, passed to commands being executed) varies from shell to shell (it is in bash, yash, mksh, zsh, but not in ksh, ash).

It only works the way you'd expect with `zsh`. Note that `zsh` array indices start at 1.

```
bash-4.4$ zsh
$ a=(before value)
$ f() echo $a[1]
$ a=(temp value) f
temp
$ echo $a[1]
before
```

Answer (score 12):

It's not just a bug, it seems to be an unimplemented feature with no plans of ever being so. This [mailing list post](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2014/09/30/1) from 2014 has this from the creator:

> > Fortunately, in bash 4.3 (patchlevel 25), you cannot just -DARRAY_EXPORT
> >     and get array variable import/export.  The code doesn't compile, and if you
> >     fix that, it does not link, and if you fix that, well, you end up with the
> >     following issue.
>
> That's a ton of trouble to go through just for this.  I don't have any
>   plans to enable array export.

Pulling from the latest git repo for Bash has this in `variables.c`:

```
  #  if ARRAY_EXPORT
        /* Array variables may not yet be exported. */
```

Suggesting that whatever is there isn't complete.

Comment: Here, it's for a function, so there's no question of exporting anything as there's no `execve()` system call being involved. See `zsh` for a shell that supports calling functions with an array temporarily set that way.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas But the environment changes (by adding a new variable) and then reverts to back, after the function  completed (I am about this case: `my_var=one func_bar`). Can we say, that `export` is adding to the environment and thus, the exporting is used here, under the hood? Look at my answer, I added the demonstration code.

Answer (score 10):

From the `man bash`'s BUGS section (the version of the `bash` is 4.3):

> BUGS
>
> ```
>    Array variables may not (yet) be exported.
> ```

---

The next code demonstrates, that a temporary variable exists in the environment, only while the function is running. When the function is completed, the temporary variable disappears.

```
### defining the "bar" function
### it pass all environment variables to the "grep" command
### and the "grep" prints the only "my_var" variable from it
bar() { env | grep my_var=; }

### calls the "bar" function with the temporary 
### variable "my_var" created and assigned.
my_var=one bar

my_var=one         ### The output. The environment contains the "my_var" variable

### checks, does the environment still have the "my_var" variable
### (It doesn't have.)
env | grep my_var=
                   ### The output is empty,
                   ### the environment doesn't contain the "my_var" variable
```

**Related information:**

- [Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264642/109397)  about the `VAR=VALUE some-command` construction.
- [Exporting an array in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5564418/2913477)
- [bash: set array env variable and de-referencing it from any shell script fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14100409/2913477)