# Confusing behavior when using IFS and read

Tags: bash

```
line="touch : touch : test.txt"
IFS=':' read scr cmd <<< "$line"
echo $scr
echo $cmd
```

**output**:

touch

touch : test.txt

```
line="touch : touch : test.txt"
IFS=':' 
read scr cmd <<< "$line"
echo $scr
echo $cmd
```

**output**:

touch

 touch   test.txt

I don't understand how the second syntax makes read remove the ':' . Any ideas?

Comment: `read` doesn't remove it - echoing the unquoted `$cmd` with `IFS` set to `:` does

Comment: I think this is a combination of that and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264635/when-can-i-use-a-temporary-ifs-for-field-splitting - `read` is not a special built-in, so setting `IFS` for read will not make it persist after `read` returns, so the lack of quoting doesn't affect the commands after it the same way as in the second example.